# Why .bash_profile couldn't set PS1 variable?

Tags: environment-variables, lfs

I set .bash_profile to

```
 exec env -i HOME=$HOME TERM=vt100 PS1='\h' /bin/bash
```

But when I login, it also show:

```
 lfs@sam:~$ env
 TERM=vt100
 PWD=/home/lfs
 PS1=${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ 
 SHLVL=1
 HOME=/home/lfs
 _=/usr/bin/env
 lfs@sam:~$
```

What happened?

How to set PS1 when login?

Thank you~

Comment: `PS1` is usually set in `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile`.  `.profile` type files are for setting environment variables.  `PS1` is a shell variable, not an environment variable.  Chances are, you have a `.bashrc` that is also setting `PS1`.

Answer (score 3):

This value of `PS1` is set by the bash system-wide configuration file `/etc/bash.bashrc`. You can override it by setting it from your `~/.bashrc`.

`PS1` is a shell variable. Its meaning depends on the shell. It should normally not be exported since it is not supposed to be in process's environments, though you can get away with it if you only ever use one shell.

Note that bash is rather quirky about configuration files: if you start a login instance of bash, it reads only `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.profile` if there is no `~/.bash_profile`. If you start a non-login interactive instance, it reads `/etc/bash.bashrc` (if configured to do so) and `~/.bashrc`. In order to get your interactive settings in login instances of bash, you should put this code in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -r ~/.profile ]; then
  . ~/.profile
fi
case $- in *i*) if [ -r ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi;; esac
```

The shell variable `$-` contains the letter `i` to indicate that the shell is interactive.